# Android: ProgressDialog not showing in Adapter Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-adapter, android-context

In my application , I have  a listview and each item has a button. If user clicks the button ,i want to execute some http connection. So i use AsyncTask in the Adapter class. Now the problem is progress dialog is not showing.

```
private class MyClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {
        private Context context;
        private ServerCall call = new ServerCall();
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog1;

        public MyClass(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            try {
                progressDialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(context, "",
                        "Please wait...", true);
                progressDialog1.setIndeterminate(true);

            } catch (final Throwable th) {

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //some tasks

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("History")) {

                Intent order = new Intent(context, ActicityA.class);
                order.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(order);

            } else {
                Intent order = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
                order.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(order);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: was onPreExcute() method called? We need mor information.

Comment: @LazyNinja yes onPreExcute() called. i see it in lagcat

Comment: Why don't you log the exception in the catch block inside the preExecute method. If you are getting an exception there, you will know what the problem is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its true that `ProgressDialog.show()` method returns a `ProgressDialog` obect, but its better to first create an object of ProgressDialog like:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog1 = new ProgressDialog();
```

and then

```
progressDialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(context, "",
                        "Please wait...", true);
```

And also, try to finish the `progressDialog1` in `onPostExecute()` by calling its `dismiss()` method.

Comment: I cant execute progressDialog1 = new ProgressDialog() this , because its syntax is new ProgressDialog(context). so i put it in constructor. But still progressdialog not showing

Comment: Here instead of private ProgressDialog progressDialog1; use private ProgressDialog progressDialog1 = new ProgreassDialog(YourParentActivity.this); And Call the progressDialog1 as this.progressDialog.show();

Comment: I use this adapter class for two activities, so how could i get parent activity

Comment: Okay, but passing context to ProgressDialog should also work. Is this AsyncTask is inside Adapter?

Comment: Okay strange then. Now Are you calling your execute() method in Adapter class. You should not call it there and also if possible, separate the AsyncTask and Adapter classes. Have you tried the solutions that I have mentioned above? If still it does not solves, then before calling the execute() method, start the progressDialog and on returning from onPostExecute() dismiss the progressDialog.

Comment: I just called another activity through intent, and there i used AsyncTask

Comment: I'm still getting the exception. I really don't understand how this answer even got accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead'

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        //dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Follow this steps 
    [0] start showing progressbar
    [1] Execute AsyncTask class
    [2] in this class one interface for post the response in main class 
    [3] Declare one interface class
    [4] get Reponse in Main Clss using interface 
    [5] dismiss Progressbar and Bind your Data 

    ex. 
    [0]

            progr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    [1]
                    MyTask task = new MyTask();
                task.setdata(new SendData() {
    [4]             @Override
                    public void GetStringResponse(String str) {
                        Log.i(General.TAG, TAG + " Overide GetString-"+str);                    
                        final String GetResponse=str;
                    // here you get response and parse it   
   [5]                               // here you can dismiss your progress bar                          
                    }
                });
                task.execute(new String[] {Newsurl[Id]});


    [2] Add interface here with Method

    SendData  objsend;

    @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(String Result)
        {
            Log.i("**********", Result);        
            objsend.GetStringResponse(Result);  
        }

        public void setdata(SendData  sendd)
        {
            Log.i(General.TAG,TAG+"Initialise Interface object");
            objsend = sendd;
        }

 [3] interface class
     public interface SendData {    
    public  abstract void GetStringResponse(String str);
}
```

Comment: I place AsyncTask inside one adapter class, And This Adapter class is standalone

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre><code>
public MyClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        progressDialog1=new ProgressDialog(context);
    }
```

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

```
    progressdialog1.setMessage("please wait while loading");
    progressdialog1.setIndeterminate(true);

    }
```